# Rally 2.0 SDK - Loading Animation/Message

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I would like to show the loading Rally animation while my queries are being loaded. Is there a method for this? How it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is place a call to mask the part of the app you wish to mask while the queries are loading, and then unmask afterwards like so:

```
Ext.getBody().mask('Loading...'); // put whatever message you want as the param
...
query
...
Ext.getBody().unmask();
```

[See the documentation here](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-mask).